# How can I avoid repetition of a function when using the same output twice in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I am playing around with *Microsoft SQL Server* in order to get familiar with the software and learn SQL. I am using a sample database containing, amongst other things, information about employees of a firm.

Here is the code I currently am working with:

```
SELECT [LoginID]
      ,[OrganizationLevel]
      ,[JobTitle]
      ,[BirthDate]
      ,[MaritalStatus]
      ,[Gender]
      ,[HireDate]
      ,[VacationHours]
      ,[SickLeaveHours]
      ,DateDiff(Year, BirthDate, GetDate()) AS 'Age'
  FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Employee]
  WHERE MaritalStatus = 'M' AND (DateDiff(Year, BirthDate, GetDate()) > 40)
  ORDER BY Gender, Age ASC;
```

As you can see, I want to display only the married employees which are over 40 years old as of today, but also display their age in the 'Age' column.

I have tried the following :

`WHERE MaritalStatus = 'M' AND ((DateDiff(Year, BirthDate, GetDate())) AS 'Age') > 40`

in order to avoid using the `DATEDIFF()` function twice but it is unsuccessful.

I guess it is related to

```
DateDiff(Year, BirthDate, GetDate()) AS 'Age'
```

being outside of `SELECT` but I cannot find another solution at the moment.

Thanks in advance to those who can enlighten me.

Comment: `DATEDIFF` doesn't do what you describe. If you want to find people over 40, as of today, you're better off subtracting 40 years from today and comparing that to the DOB column. (Hint `DATEDIFF(year,'20011231','20020101')` returns `1`)

Comment: What is the result of your query ? Do you have an error ?

Comment: @CoskunOzogul I get the error : `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near 'AS'.` (note: I have edited the line in the original post, the parentheses weren't positionned correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a couple of `APPLY`s to calculate the actual ages and reduce repetition, but be aware that the system should already be optimizing this anyway.

```
SELECT [LoginID]
      ,[OrganizationLevel]
      ,[JobTitle]
      ,[BirthDate]
      ,[MaritalStatus]
      ,[Gender]
      ,[HireDate]
      ,[VacationHours]
      ,[SickLeaveHours]
      ,Age
  FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Employee]
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(year,BurthDate,GetDate()) as PotentialAge) a
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN DATEADD(year,PotentialAge,BirthDate) > GetDate() 
               THEN PotentialAge - 1 ELSE PotentialAge END as Age) b
  WHERE MaritalStatus = 'M' AND Age > 40
  ORDER BY Gender, Age ASC;
```

As pointed out in the comments, we have to do more work to generate the actual age because `DATEDIFF` counts *transitions*.

Answer (score 0):

The AS statement can only be in Select statement.

```
SELECT [LoginID]
  ,[OrganizationLevel]
  ,[JobTitle]
  ,[BirthDate]
  ,[MaritalStatus]
  ,[Gender]
  ,[HireDate]
  ,[VacationHours]
  ,[SickLeaveHours]
  ,DateDiff(Year, BirthDate, GetDate()) AS 'Age'
  FROM [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources].[Employee]
  WHERE MaritalStatus = 'M' AND (DateDiff(Year, BirthDate, GetDate()) > 40)
  ORDER BY Gender, DateDiff(Year, BirthDate, GetDate()) ASC;
```

You have to repeat the function each time you want to use it...
I think this is what you want to do. Correct ?

Comment: The code I've put above works (even though it is not as accurate as it should be, as @Damien_The_Unbeliever pointed out earlier), but I just wanted to know if there was a way not to use `DATEDIFF()` twice.

Answer (score -1):

I think your schema information is not correct. 
Try to remove [AdventureWorks2014].[HumanResources] and put only [Employee]

```
  SELECT [LoginID]
  ,[OrganizationLevel]
  ,[JobTitle]
  ,[BirthDate]
  ,[MaritalStatus]
  ,[Gender]
  ,[HireDate]
  ,[VacationHours]
  ,[SickLeaveHours]
  ,DateDiff(Year, BirthDate, GetDate()) AS 'Age'
 FROM Employee]
 WHERE MaritalStatus = 'M' AND (DateDiff(Year, BirthDate, GetDate()) > 40)
 ORDER BY Gender, Age ASC;
```

Comment: What do you mean ? `[AdventureWorks2014]` is the full DB and `[HumanResources].[Employee]` is the table. There is no "`[Employee]` only" table in the database.